Angular Nested Routing: Navigation Not Updating with RouterLink
I have a route config
 {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: UserDashboardPageComponent,
    title: 'xyz',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardSummaryComponent,
        title: 'Panel użytkownika',
      },
      {
        path: 'official-exams',
        component: OfficialMaturaExamsComponent,
        title: 'aaa',
      },
      {
        path: 'mock-exams',
        component: MockMaturaExamsComponent,
        title: 'bbb',
      },
      {
        path: 'exams-exercises',
        component: MaturaExamsExcercisesComponent,
        title: 'ccc',
      },

and then the dashboard page:
<section class="flex h-[100vh]">
  <app-dashboard-navigation class="min-w-[20rem]"></app-dashboard-navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>

to navigate through sections i created a card:
<div
  class="flex gap-5 justify-left items-center text-center pl-5 group hover:cursor-pointer m-3 backdrop-blur-md"
  [routerLink]="link"
>
  <ng-icon
    class="text-3xl group-hover:text-cyan-600 transition-all duration-300"
    [name]="icon"
  ></ng-icon>
  <p
    class="text-xl font-bold group-hover:text-cyan-600 transition-all duration-300"
  >
    {{ title }}
  </p>
</div>

and then the nav:
menu: any[] = [
    {
      icon: 'tablerAtom',
      title: '',
      route: '/official-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerPaperclip',
      title: '',
      route: '/mock-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerNotebook',
      title: '',
      route: 'exams-exercises',
    },
  ];

and then:
 @for(opt of menu; track opt){
    <app-dashboard-nav-card
      [icon]="opt.icon"
      [title]="opt.title"
      [link]="opt.route"
    ></app-dashboard-nav-card>
    }

so with the nav on the left i want to navigate to /dashboard/official-exams or /dashboard//mock-exams.
But now it doesnt work. It doesnt throw any error in console, but its a blink change in the url and nothing changes.

You need to adjust your links specified in menu to be relative rather than absolute.
This would allow routerLink to resolve them relative to url of the ActivatedRoute ( /dashboard in your case)
menu: any[] = [
    {
      icon: 'tablerAtom',
      title: '',
      // resolved to /dashboard/official-exams
      route: './official-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerPaperclip',
      title: '',
      // resolved to /dashboard/mock-exams
      route: './mock-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerNotebook',
      title: '',
      // resolved to /dashboard/exams-exercises
      route: './exams-exercises',
    },
  ];

There is more info in the docs about Using Relative Paths
Hope that helps :)

thanks sir for trying for help but it still didnt help
